# Are questions that are the reverse of an existing question still a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Imagine an original question that goes like this:

> Q: How do I do this thing?  When I do it the "wrong way" it works
>   until I try to do this other thing afterwards
>
> A: You don't want to do it like that, here is the "right way" to do
>   it.

Now a question comes along that goes like this:

> Q: How do I do this thing?  The "right way" works, but I don't like it
>
> A: Do it this "wrong way".

Is the second question a duplicate of the first?  The solution the OP of the second question wants is found in the original question's question, not its answer.

---

The motivation behind this question is this question:  [Append unit type to the result of a calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905407/append-unit-type-to-the-result-of-a-calculation)

I closed it as a duplicate when I was going through a pile of similar questions (I have the gold badge for sass), but the OP didn't like that and convinced 5 people that it wasn't a duplicate and had it reopened.  This is the question I used to close it with:  [Adding a unit to a number in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513395/adding-a-unit-to-a-number-in-sass)

To make things worse, this question is now the #1 result on Google when you search for "sass append unit".  I realize that whether the solution is "right" or "wrong" might be a matter of opinion, but the "wrong" way has been perpetuated so often that it repeatedly trips up users who don't know any better.  This question being the one users are going to turn to first is only making things worse.

If you look at the other top results, they either get it right or are not relevant:

2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/correctly-adding-unit-number/
3. http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sass-units/
4. Official documentation for functions, nothing relevant here
5. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sass-lang/4uHbZ9OL48Q
6. Not relevant
7. Not relevant
8. Not relevant
9. Not relevant
10. http://sass-guidelin.es/

From CSS Tricks:

> While this method works, it is far from ideal because it results in implicitly casting the initial value as a string. Indeed, if you try doing math with the $length value from now on, you'll see that Sass quickly throws an error because it cannot do math operators with a string.

From Chris Eppstein, one of the maintainers of Sass, on Google Groups:

> No, don't do this. $width_value will be a string that looks like a number instead of a number.

From Sass Guidelines:

> The most common mistake I can think of regarding numbers in Sass, is thinking that units are just some strings that can be safely appended to a number. While that sounds true, it is certainly not how units work. Think of units as algebraic symbols. For instance, in the real world, multiplying 5 inches by 5 inches gives you 25 square inches. The same logic applies to Sass.

We are doing a real disservice to our users by not pointing them to the correct answer, which we already have in multiple places on SO.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not really what duplicates are for.  If the questions are substantially different, and *especially* if the author of the second question explicitly states their dissatisfaction (however well or poorly reasoned) with the answers to the first question, then they're not exact duplicates.

One thing you can do in such situations, if you feel that the existing answers to a highly voted question are bad, is simply post your own answer explaining how to better do what the OP wants (hopefully, in a way that will be acceptable to them, and addresses their stated concerns).

[I just tried to do that myself.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905407/append-unit-type-to-the-result-of-a-calculation/31082730#31082730)  Had to learn some SASS to do it, but thankfully, it seems to work just like I expected it to.  We'll see how the OP feels about it, and whether it will get voted up.